# order rows by columns names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to order my rows in table in such a way that rows whose `ticker_flag = 1` or `twitter_flag=1` should display first and other rows whose `ticker_flag = 0` or `twitter_flag=0` shouldm display after previous rows.
I am giving image of my table structure. 
 I just need to display rows first whose ticker_flag or twitter_flag is set to 1. So please tell me how should I achieve this ?[image]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ticker_flag DESC, twitter_flag DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope this is useful

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ticker_flag DESC, twitter_flag DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best way would do it to do it inside your SQL query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE foo = baa
ORDER BY ticker_flag ASC, twitter_flag ASC;
```

Hope this helps.